# Species identification: plant with pitfall trap-like structures

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found this plant in Tuscany (Italy, mediterranean climate, about 60 m above mean sea level). Photos were taken at roughly the beginning of spring after a period of drought followed by a couple days of rain. Average temperature oscillates between 7-10°C, relative humidity is around 75-80%.

Unfortunately I didn't have a ruler at hand but the plant was not very tall, I'd say about 12-15 cm (5-6 inches) at most.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Family is likely Araceae. Not familiar enough with Italian flora to know possible candidates. I may have time to dig in later, but I suppose some European users more familiar with possible candidates will be able to respond before I have time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is probably a plant in the genus [*Arisarum*](http://luirig.altervista.org/flora/taxa/floraspecie.php?genere=Arisarum) based on the almost complete covered inflorescence ("trap-like" structure). In particular, it looks most like [*Arisarum vulgare* (common name: Friar's cowl)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arisarum_vulgare). This plant is found throughout the Mediterranean region including Italy.

The striped structure with a "lid" isn't a trap, but instead an inflorescence (branch bearing multiple flowers — in this case a spadix with its bract being the "trap"). The inflorescences are from the plant with the rounded-arrowhead shaped leaves.

That leaf shape is characteristic of several genera in the Arum family ([Araceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araceae)), but the size and very rounded tip looks most like specimens of *Arisarum vulgare*.

The size and early spring flowering time also fit what is described for this species.

[image: Arisarum vulgare flower closeup from wikipedia]
Source: user Hectonichus on Wikimedia Commons —
License: [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)